# why for loop is not accepting boolean value directly?

Tags: java

compilation error : The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(true;true;true) {//compilation error

        }
    }
}
```

but when I tried this way, there is no compilation error

```
    class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (getBoolean(); true; getBoolean()) {

        }
    }

    public static boolean getBoolean() {
    return true;
    }
}
```

getBoolean() is returning a boolean value,so for the first case why the for loop is not accepting boolean value directly?

Comment: what are you trying to do? this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your question appears to be built on a false premise. I do not receive the error `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable` when compiling the first sample; I receive the error that `true` is not a statement, which is entirely accurate.

Comment: @blm Does it matter? It's a valid question.

Comment: @Voldemort it does matter. If there isn't a use case for this functionality then there's no reason it should compile.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the reply but I am using eclipse IDE and in that its showing The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

Comment: @ChrisHayes same here.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Interesting. Seems like a classic case of Eclipse being Eclipse. Ideone does a much better job here: http://ideone.com/4dLmqT

Comment: @blm It's not off-topic. Nothing wrong with learning about the language's behaviour. You can vote to close this if you want. Edit: Ah you need the rep. Well, somebody else can vote to close it if they find it off-topic.

Comment: Just a note: If you don't want to do anything for initialization and update, just leave it empty. (You can even leave the middle expression empty, it defaults to `true`.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14):

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement

ForStatementNoShortIf:
    for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) StatementNoShortIf

ForInit:
    StatementExpressionList
    LocalVariableDeclaration

ForUpdate:
    StatementExpressionList

StatementExpressionList:
    StatementExpression
    StatementExpressionList , StatementExpression
```

[Then](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8):

```
 StatementExpression:
    Assignment
    PreIncrementExpression
    PreDecrementExpression
    PostIncrementExpression
    PostDecrementExpression
    MethodInvocation
    ClassInstanceCreationExpression
```

As you can see `Method Invocation` is allowed and `literal value` is not.

Answer (score 4):

According to doc

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

And intialization and increment must be the expression(assignment) not simple boolean but in java function call is considered as expression so it will evaluate correctly.